# Porting CMake to OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, macports, osx-yosemite

I am trying to update my Macport for Yosemite and installation of cmake fails.
Here's the log file:

```
:info:configure CMake Error at Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:213 (message):
:info:configure   CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.10' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:
:info:configure 
:info:configure    ""
:info:configure 
:info:configure   is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
:info:configure   CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to empty.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 10.10 SDK to do. Try updating XCode to 6.1 before. See [bug report](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/44581) and Yosemite related [information](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/YosemiteProblems).

Comment: similar problems for gcc4.5 , 4.7 , 4.8 . could not resolve with update to 6.1. I guess I'll wait a bit longer till I upgrade macports.